# C++ open link with ShellExecute

Tags: c++, url, hyperlink, shellexecute

If I write like this:

```
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "www.google.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Everything's okay and is as it has to be.

But I want so that user could enter a link where he wants to go.

```
std::cout<<"Enter the link: ";
            char link;
            std::cin>>link;
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", link, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

In this case I get an `invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const CHAR*` error.

So, is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code only gets one character in as the link. You need to make link a type able to hold the value of the link and also read stdio in. Making link a std::string will do this but then you need to take care of how it is passed to ShellExecute

```
std::cout<<"Enter the link: ";
std::string link;
std::cin>>link;
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", link.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should declare your input as char*

```
char *link = new char[2048];

...
delete[] link;
```

The const char* in ShellExecute is just a promise that it won't change the input.
After changing the declaration, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Where does cin write to - link points to no memory - you need to allocate some memory with malloc for a buffer and also cast the char* to const char*