# How to open a url from a c++ program in windows?

Tags: c++, url, shellexecute

I want my c++ code to open a url.However all the threads online promote using ShellExecute with an already specified url. My code requires the user to input the url and the program must then open it in a browser so the url is in the form of a string.
Much Appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open URL from C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347950/open-url-from-c-code)

Comment: Also relevant: [C++ open link with ShellExecute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168646/c-open-link-with-shellexecute). Can you explain the problem with ShellExecute? you can pass the url as parameter to the function, so you can pass a url from an user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that :

```
std::string myUrl;
std::cin >> myUrl;
system(std::string("start " + myUrl).c_str());
```

?

Comment: Yes exactly! I was using pointers so I had to make a few changes but this worked! Thanks.

Comment: `system()` opens the console. Is there a way of keeping it from doing that?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should to the trick for you, of course, if you are using Windows:

```
    std::cout<<"Enter the link: ";
    std::string link;
    std::cin>>link;
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", link.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: That gives an error saying "'HINSTANCE ShellExecuteW(HWND,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,INT)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'". It should be `ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", link.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`.

Comment: Actually, it should be `_T("open")` if you want it to work with all character formats.  Except you'd also need to pass the link as a wide string.  Better to use explicit variants `ShellExecuteA` or `ShellExecuteW` as required.