# Open a dynamic URL using C++

Tags: c++, date, url, iteration

Got the following URL - https://barbaraperes.com/2017/08/31/2017_08_31.csv, being 2017 the year, 08 the month and 31 the day.

Currently I'm building a script that goes through all days, months and years from a given moment to the present time. For every day, the script changes a url (string) inserting the days, months and years, and [opens it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11168746/9902288).

This is the current code

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    struct tm date;

    date.tm_year = 2007 - 1900; // tm_year (int) years since 1900
    date.tm_mon = 6; // tm_mon (int) months since January (0-11)
    date.tm_mday = 1; // tm_mday (int) day of the month (1-31)

    time_t end_date = time(NULL);

    std::cout << " =========================================================== \n";

    std::cout << "Let's go!\n";

    std::cout << " =========================================================== \n";

    for (; mktime(&date) < end_date; ++date.tm_mday) {

        std::cout << "Defining the new date... \n";

        char year[16];
        char month[16];
        char day[16];

        strftime(year, sizeof(year), "%Y", &date);
        strftime(month, sizeof(month), "%m", &date); // %m writes month as a decimal number (01-12)
        strftime(day, sizeof(day), "%d", &date);

        std::cout << "New date defined! \n";

        std::cout << "Year: " << year << "\n";
        std::cout << "Month: "<< month << "\n";
        std::cout << "Day: "<<  day << "\n\n";

        std::cout << "Make the url dynamic: \n";

        std::string url = "https://barbaraperes.com////__.csv";
        // https://barbaraperes.com/2017/08/31/2017_08_31.csv

        std::string str1 = year;
        std::string str2 = month;
        std::string str3 = day;

        url.insert(25, str1);
        url.insert(30, str2);
        url.insert(33, str3);
        url.insert(36, str1);
        url.insert(41, str2);
        url.insert(44, str3);

        std::cout << "This is the dynamic url: " << url << "\n\n";

    std::cout << " =========================================================== \n";
    }

    std::cout << " =========================================================== \n";

}
```

It works fine until the day reaches 31, as we can see in the next image

[image: Output]

Once the day reaches 31 (end of the first month which is July), it will start printing empty days and the month won't change to 08 (August)

[image: Output_no_day]

How can we solve this?

Comment: _which got as output `Exmplr`_ After debugging by eyes, I got `axmplr` instead. ;-) _but I'm soo tired from studying_ Not that computer programming is easy-peasy (always) - it's a hard job and makes me dizzy sometimes (although my wife still believes I'm sitting all days in my office and playing with computer whole time). Stay calm, have a sleep, cheer up, and fight this through. Yes, you can. (What you presented in your Q looks actually like a plan. Just follow it.)

Comment: Yes you are right, `axmplr`. I did another exercise with `Exmplr` ;)

Comment: What exactly is the challenge you're facing? What is the specific problem you're stuck with? More general, follow [ask]. Also, get some sleep if you're tired. You'll make more mistakes than you'll fix and you actually learn stuff by processing it in your dreams.

Comment: The problem is how to make the url dynamic.

Comment: _The problem is how to make the url dynamic._ What do you mean with dynamic? According to your existing code, you build the URL at runtime. IMHO, this is as dynamic as necessary. Once you finished it for a specific date, the next step could be to wrap that code in a loop to iterate over dates (as sketched in your 2nd sentence).

Comment: That's what i mean with dynamic, have it inside of the loop and iterate over the dates.

Comment: @Scheff it's almost done, but not I'm stuck with a problem that if you know how to help would be great. It seems like the problem was in the conversion from character array to string, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-character-array-to-string-in-c/ .

Comment: @BárbaraPeres Update your question and remove everything that's not relevant anymore and put your current problem in it instead.

Comment: Thank you @TedLyngmo, I just fixed it as you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could step your days forward. This prints 400 days, starting at 2007/07/01.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::tm date{};

    date.tm_year = 2007 - 1900; // tm_year (int) years since 1900
    date.tm_mon = 6;            // tm_mon (int) months since January (0-11)
    date.tm_mday = 1;           // tm_mday (int) day of the month (1-31)
    date.tm_hour = 12;          // mid day

    std::time_t current = std::mktime(&date);

    for(int i = 0; i < 400; ++i) {
        std::memcpy(&date, std::localtime(&current), sizeof(date));

        std::cout << date.tm_year + 1900 << " " << date.tm_mon + 1 << " " << date.tm_mday << "\n";

        current += 60 * 60 * 24; // add one day
    }
}
```

And here's a fancier version with support to create your URL:s on the fly:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

struct mytm : std::tm {        // inherit "tm" to extend it a little
    mytm(int year, int month, int day) : tm{}, current{} {
        tm_year = year - 1900;
        tm_mon = month - 1;
        tm_mday = day;
        tm_hour = 12;
        current = std::mktime(this);
    }

    void add_days(int days) {
        current += days * 60 * 60 * 24;
        std::memcpy(this, std::localtime(&current), sizeof(std::tm));
    }

    std::string strftime(const char* format, std::size_t bufsize = 64) {
        std::string retval(bufsize, ' ');
        std::size_t len = std::strftime(&retval[0], retval.size(), format, this);
        retval.resize(len);
        return retval;
    }

    std::time_t current;
};

int main() {
    mytm date(2007, 7, 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 400; ++i) {
        std::string url =
            date.strftime("https://barbaraperes.com/%Y/%m/%d/%Y_%m_%d.csv", 51);
        std::cout << url << "\n";
        date.add_days(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't compile the last code, I'm getting `[Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]` on Line 21, Col 53.

Comment: Also `[Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` on Line 6, Col 44 and 55.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the first error so you can try copying again. I was assuming C++17, but it seems you are using an older version. What version are you using exactly?

Comment: Thank you, it works but i can only award the bounty in 18h from now. I'm using Dec-C++ and don't know where to find the version...

Comment: @BárbaraPeres That's fine :-) The compiler usually has an option to let you select the version of C++ you'd like to use, but if it's really old, you may not have that option. I haven't used Dec-C++ myself.

Comment: This one doesn't have, as far as i know... Thank you again for your attention and care, you made me very happy :)

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the day after the loop condition is evaluated and yet you are relying on the call to mktime() in the loop condition to normalize your time.

The first thing you should do after incrementing the day is call mktime to normalize the time.

```
   for (; mktime(&date) < end_date; ++date.tm_mday) {
      mktime(&date);
```